# How to set first position of character in textbox in Textbox click event ---Chrome Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, cross-browser, httpbrowsercapabilities

See bellow code 
            Here is HTML

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtInTime" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox" Width="60px"
    OnClick="fnFocus(this.id)" ></asp:TextBox>
```

here is javascript

```
   function fnFocus(id) {
   document.getElementById(id).focus();    
   }
```

Above code working in all browser expect chrome...
I want textbox click to focus of textbox at first position..In chrome not comming in first position of character..
please help...
Any Suggestion...??

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using [`setSelectionRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Input.setSelectionRange):

```
function fnFocus(id) {
    var input = document.getElementById(id);
    input.focus();
    input.setSelectionRange(0, 0);
}
```

Demo: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NEtWc/1/)

Comment: Its working in Chrome.... but it effects in IE. In IE its working for 1st click, but if you click 2nd time its not working

Answer (score 0):

setSelecionRange is not working for me in Chrome.

Try this X-Browser:

//Function to set the cursor position and then we set the position for your textbox

```
$.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) {this.each(function(index, elem) {
if (elem.setSelectionRange) {
  elem.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
} else if (elem.createTextRange) {
  var range = elem.createTextRange();
  range.collapse(true);
  range.moveEnd('character', pos);
  range.moveStart('character', pos);
  range.select();
}   });   return this; };

$('#txtInTime').setCursorPosition(0);
```

// In your code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtInTime"...... OnClick="$(this).setCursorPosition(0);"></asp:TextBox>
```

[Source](http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jqueryhtml5-input-focus-cursor-positions/)

Comment: sure? the "$('#txtInTime').setCursorPosition(0);" should be on the onclick attribute like :

Comment: sorry...continue here....If you fires the function in ONCLICK of the field, it would be something like that:   <asp:TextBox ID="txtInTime" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox" Width="60px"
    OnClick="$(this).setCursorPosition(0);" ></asp:TextBox>